# Regex to match "&" only if preceded by a single word and space?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to match ampersand in this expression only if it is preceded by a single word and space. (It should not match anything beyond the ampersand unless it's just preceded by one word and space.) I need to match only the first surname at the beginning of a file name and only those that begin with the letter A.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lI5eL8/1)

```
Paul & Mary Atkins - (match should be: Paul & Mary Atkins)
John Arnold & Dave Badman - (match should be: John Arnold)
----DO NOT MATCH----
John Baines & Dave Adams -
```

For use in File Renamer, flavor is javascript.

Comment: Not clear since 2nd and 3rd examples both have a word and a space before `&`

Comment: Why do you want to match the second and don't want to match the third?

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
/(^\w+ &.*)/
```

matches all lines with a single word followed by a space and `&`. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pC0fY9/1).

Note that this matches only the first line in your example.